# why the same powershell command run on the powershell console but not using os.system?

Tags: python, powershell, os.system

I would like to include a command to create a 7zip archive withinin a Python script. Since I am working on Windows, I need to pass the command to the powershell console. I am planning to do it with `os.system` (I am aware that this is not the best way to do it and that I should use `subprocess`, but I really just need a quick fix and it would not be time effective for me to learn to use a new module in this context).
The following command works if run from the powershell console

```
&'C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7z' a -mx=0 X:/myarch.zip X:/myarch
```

So I recreate the same string within python like this:

```
cmdl = r"&'C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7z' a -mx=0 X:/myarch.zip X:/myarch"
```

The string is interpreted as follow:

```
"&'C:\\\\Program Files\\\\7-Zip\\\\7z' a -mx=0 X:/myarch.zip X:/myarch"
```

Now, if I copy-paste the above string within the powershell console, it runs without problems. However, if I run it within python using  `os.system(cmdl)` I got the following error

```
"The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect"
```

Why is this the case and how can I fix this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.system` is meant for executing cmd commands, cmd commands can be ran in powershell maybe after all powershell is a bit advanced but I'm sure that you can't run a cmd command in powershell, henceforth your code is not working.

However a creative solution for executing a powershell command **from** python(not **using** python) would be to write your command into a .ps file(powershell script)and then run it using `os.startfile()`(use this code: `os.startfile("script.ps")`)

Comment: I have rewritten the command to work on cmd rather than powershell and now it works fine.

Comment: @fednem i edited my post, if you still want to do a powershell command then you could use what I said

Comment: there's no need to save to a ps1 file. You can call `powershell` directly from cmd